# How to Order Sequence between html tag "Required" and javascript "onClick"

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

I have simple form to add an item into database built with PHP.  I use html attribute Required like this :

> `<input type="text" name="iditem" required/>`

To prevent submit button in sending blank value into database.

I also have javascript "onClick" on the submit button like this :

> `<input type="submit" onClick="return confirm('Add this item?')" />`

What I want to ask is... How to make **required** attribute can be executed first before the **submit button** ?

Thanks guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "onsubmit" parameter in `<form>` and avoid the "onclick" on submit button:

```html
<form action="test2.php" onsubmit="return confirm('Add this item?')" >
  <input type="text" required />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Glad to help :D

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach here is to use plain `JavaScript` to do all the heavy lifting. Let's take a quick look.

First we set out HTML form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
  Username: <input id="username" type="text" name="username">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, pay attention to the `form` directive which mentions `method`, `action` and `onsubmit`. Let's go over all of those part by part.

I am sure you are completely aware as to what `method` and `action` do, but for the `onsubmit` part, it's linked to a JavaScript function called `validateForm()` which is defined as below:

```
function validateForm() {
  var username = document.getElementById( 'username' ).value;
  if( !username ) {
    return false;
  } 

  return true;
}
```

This function gets the value of the `username` element in the form and returns `false` if it's empty, and `true` otherwise. What this does is that it tells the event triggers to go forward with submitting the form to `action` using the `method` verb if the resultant value was `true`; if it was `false`, however, it just stops the execution. Much like we use the `return` keyword to break the current control.

So, in a way, it's triggered before your `onClick` handler. IN a very subtle way in the sense that it will not let the form get posted **if** the validation fails.

Now, of course, you can edit it to suit your needs by just adding a `confirm` dialogue as it'll return `true` if `OK` or `YES` is pressed and `false` otherwise. But this should give you a good example as to what all you can with the [onsubmit attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_onsubmit.asp) in particular, and the [event attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) in general.

I hope this answers your question! You can find a fiddle [here](http://jsbin.com/tukikename/edit?html,js,console,output).